# How to create a local-server that the web-browser control can use

Tags: c#, webserver, tcp, wininet

For my newest windows-application I want to create an interface that is web-based using the web-browser control, and I want to make Ajax work on it. Since all the content will be loaded by the web-browser control itself I want to create a web-server that would work on a localhost port and serve my content to the web-browser when it accesses a special url, example:

http://localhost:3454

How can I create a web-server that windows will route requests to? I just need to know about the right API/WinInet commands to start receiving the requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunate for you, .NET comes with a pretty decent Web Server built into the framework.

Look at the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class.

It supports both synchronous and asynchronous modes:

> The synchronous model is appropriate
>   if your application should block while
>   waiting for a client request and if
>   you want to process only one request
>   at a time. Using the synchronous
>   model, call the GetContext method,
>   which waits for a client to send a
>   request. The method returns an
>   HttpListenerContext object to you for
>   processing when one occurs.
>
> In the more complex asynchronous
>   model, your application does not block
>   while waiting for requests and each
>   request is processed in its own
>   execution thread. Use the
>   BeginGetContext method to specify an
>   application-defined method to be
>   called for each incoming request.
>   Within that method, call the
>   EndGetContext method to obtain the
>   request, process it, and respond.

This guy is great because it uses the native web server that is built into modern versions of Windows (XP SP2+ and Server 2003+).

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is open a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) [socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) to port 3454 and [listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx) for connections. Then you need to service each incoming connection by reading the stream, parsing the HTTP headers and content (if applicable).